# Redirect .jpeg files to .php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make some image optimizations and so I want every requested .jpeg images to be redirected to my transformer.php file for the conversion and then the transformed will the be sent to the client. The actual problem is that I've been using my .htaccess rewrite rule to make that redirect possible but it doesn't seem to get that file... The chrome response keeps saying "This request has no response data available", whereas I've some mock data written in the file.

My rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)\.jpeg$ /img/transformer.php [L]
```

I don't know why it isn't working. Glad if you could help. Thank you!

Comment: I am no rewrite genius, but it does not look like you are telling your `transformer.php` script which file (jpg) it should be processing

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know the first part of the rule grabs every  .jpeg image in page and it fetches every .jpeg image correctly, but the transformer file doesn't run at all... It says no response, even with my mock data